# className conditions not dynamic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to show and hide a column depending on a boolean state.
But it will only fire once.

I'm trying to set display none and block depending a boolean state, my app updates the boolean state but my column won't read it

```
<Row style={ (values.boolean ? styles.visible : styles.hidden) }>
```

I'm using the method setState to change my boolean:

```
this.setState({ boolean: Object.keys(response.tracks).length && Object.values(response.tracks).length ? true : false })
```

Edit: Sorry for the miss spell on the setstate, my code was right though

My app will actually update the state but the row just won't change

```
const styles = {
    visible: {
        display: 'block'
    },
    hidden: {
        display: 'none'
    }
}
```

Edit: I found the problem, I was trying to setState on the wrong path of a large object

Comment: the set state should have only the name as key. Try `this.setState({ boolean: true })`

Comment: Please include a [mcve] since we can't help if we can't see.

Comment: Did you explicitly give any conditions in your `shouldComponentUpdate` method?

Comment: Please add `styles.visible` and `styles.hidden` values

Comment: it only changes onces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Panther already answered to you:

this.setState gets a simple object with key-value as a parameter - all you need to do is to change the call to:

```
this.setState({ boolean: true })
```

Comment: Well not really, Im using a promise and I need to check the value before setting it to true. this is my code this.setState({ boolean: Object.keys(response.tracks).length && Object.values(response.tracks).length ? true : false })

Comment: My answer was how to change the state correctly - before you edit the message you used a syntax that doesn't work right - if you need to validate stuff before changing the state so do it :)